# Sliding images with css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple image slider.

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#slide1_images').on('click', 'img', function(){ 
    $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -450+"px)");
  });
});
```

The problem seems that it does not get the click on the right image but it takes the click on the next one. Why?

Here is the runnable exmaple:

http://jsfiddle.net/y4BkQ/

Comment: `.index()` returns a `0` based index. Do `+ ($(this).index() + 1) * 450 +` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/y4BkQ/1/

Comment: you are the best man!, put the answer i flag it like answered

Comment: this look better man @squint http://jsfiddle.net/y4BkQ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.index() returns a 0 based index. + ($(this).index() + 1) * 450 +